# Twilio SMS delivery to DND number

Tags: sms, twilio

I am sending SMS using Twilio API. During testing i found that it sometimes delivered message to the phone number but does not sends all the time. This is the case of DND activated numbers(Do Not Call List).

I knew this is because of Sender routing done by Twilio. When Twilio sends SMS using a number(only numeric sender-FROM), i received the message, but when it sends message using some alphanumeric sender(like DM-044138), it does not delivers the message.

Now my question is do we have any access to change this ? Can we set something that could guarantee the delivery even for the DND numbers ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Surely sending to a Do Not Dial number is going to get you in a heap of trouble, as it will be illegal, at least in some jurisdictions?

Comment: Sending to a Do Not Dial number is not going to get me in a heap of trouble, as i am sending information which the owner of the number expect. Not sending that information to the number will cause the owner of that number will result in his quitting from the service.

Comment: Also as i mentioned in the question itself that sending succeeded in some cases. I tested that with my own DND activated number.

Comment: In which country are you sending these messages?

Comment: Is the problem instead *why* they're on a DND list? If you've found a loophole to contact people you *shouldn't*, that doesn't mean that you should exploit it. Please remember that if the subscriber hasn't given consent for you to contact them, that would be illegal in some jurisdictions. (as would falsifying the sender information)

Comment: I am sending to India

Comment: @RowlandShaw you are right. Sending message to someone without their consent is wrong. But what about those who has given the permission and asked us to send them info via SMS ?

Comment: So the issue then is "why are these numbers on the DND list, even when they've subscribed (and not cancelled their subscription)" - which sounds like an issue to raise with Twilio customer support, and not a programming issue, so is off topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you are sending it to India.

Please review the following.

This feature is only available when sending messages to supported countries

As you can see from the list below India is not a supported country.

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/what-countries-does-twilio-support-alphanumeric-sender-id

Comment: This is not the case i have asked for. You describe a totally different thing. Out of scope of the question.

Comment: You are attempting to send a message from an Alpha Numeric number to Someone in India and it fails but it works with a numeric sender. That is exactly what I have addressed. You cannot send Messages using Alpha Numeric Senders to someone in India. Even if the person told you they were on a DND list which is carrier maintained that would still not allow you to use an Alpha Numeric Sender even if they left that list